# Applying another visa again so soon

Tags: visas, japan

I'm on a 30-day visit relative Japan visa right now and I'll be back to my home country 1st week of May.

My question is, do I have to wait for a certain period of time before I could apply for another visa again? Like about a month or so?

I am planning to apply, tourist visa next time with no guarantor.

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not need to wait for a certain period of time.

I once had a business-type visa that I needed to be replaced with a tourist visa. Just apply for the tourist visa normally (make sure to mention in the application form the previous recent stay) and *provide the passport containing the currently active visa*. They will cancel it and issue you a new one.